# How do I go about debugging Varnish not starting correctly?

Tags: debian, varnish

I'm attempting to run Varnish, but it seems that a child process is dying on startup.  Can anyone suggest the best way for me to go about debugging what's going wrong?

**Background**

I have a raspberry pi on which I'd installed Debian, which was running varnish fine.
Recently, I decided to install Raspbian (An OS based on Debian, but optimised for the raspberry pi).  To do this, I did a fresh install and used puppet to make sure that I had all the same settings as I did previously.

The only substantial difference between the two setups I can think of is that Raspbian uses a later version of Debian (Wheezy) than I had been using previously (Squeeze), so came with Varnish 3, rather than 2.

**Debugging attempts so far:**

I looked in /var/logs/syslog and found the following:

```
Sep 21 22:26:28 interceptor varnishd[15056]: Platform: Linux,3.1.9+,armv6l,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
Sep 21 22:26:28 interceptor varnishd[15056]: child (15064) Started
Sep 21 22:26:28 interceptor varnishd[15056]: Pushing vcls failed:#012CLI communication error (hdr)
Sep 21 22:26:28 interceptor varnishd[15056]: Stopping Child
Sep 21 22:26:28 interceptor varnishd[15056]: Child (15064) died signal=11
Sep 21 22:26:28 interceptor varnishd[15056]: Child (-1) said Child starts
Sep 21 22:26:28 interceptor varnishd[15056]: Child cleanup complete
Sep 21 22:26:28 interceptor varnishd[15056]: Manager got SIGINT
```

I tried googling for the error, but couldn't find anything useful.

I also ran strace -f whilst restarting varnish, but obviously that returned a lot of output and I wasn't sure what to look for.  I grepped for the pid of the child process (15064), but that didn't seem to match anything.
The strace did contain lots of lines like

```
[pid 15114] close(131072)               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)                                                                                                                                  
[pid 15114] close(131071)               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)                                                                                                                          
[pid 15114] close(131070)               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)                                                                                                                                  
[pid 15114] close(131069)               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)                                                                                                                                  
[pid 15114] close(131068)               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)                                                                                                                                  
[pid 15114] close(131067)               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)                                                                                                                                  
[pid 15114] close(131066)               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
```

but I'm not sure if this is normal or perhaps a result of my problem, rather that its cause.

Any advice on how I should proceed is much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [raspberrypi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) but please [search](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Comment: I've just searched that site for "varnish" - the only result was a reference to Polyurethane Varnish.  Are you sure that's the best place to ask about debugging a segfault?

Answer (score 3):

The best output on failures during start is to stdout/stderr - but the default init scripts stop this output from being displayed.

Try running just `varnishd -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl` - this should show you any errors in loading your VCL.

Comment: The only output I get from that is `WARNING: Taking over SHMFILE marked as owned by running process (pid=25946)`
If I run it a second time, I get no output at all, so I don't think it's a problem with the VCL file.

Comment: @lucas Does the init script report a successful start when you use it to start/restart?

Comment: When I restart I get no errors, just `
Stopping HTTP accelerator: varnishd.
Starting HTTP accelerator: varnishd.
`

Answer (score 2):

Try attaching running varnish with some very simple flags:

varnishd  -l 8m  -s file,/tmp,8m -b localhost:8080 -a 0.0.0.0:80 -w 2

and then attach the gdb debugger and see if you can find out why the child is segfaulting